# Why not send the Ring to the Undying Lands?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-one-ring

This is sort of a multi-part question that adds up to one larger question:

1. Can Sauron get to the Undying Lands? ([another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20297/would-saurons-army-reach-the-undying-lands-if-the-ring-was-not-destroyed) seems to have produced the answer to this - "No")
2. Is the One Ring still dangerous even if Sauron can't possibly get to it?
3. Is Elrond strong enough to resist the Ring?
4. Could the Ring be taken to the Undying Lands, perhaps by Frodo, Bilbo, or Elrond?

Assuming the answers to these questions are 1. no, 2. not really, 3. yes, and 4. yes, then wouldn't it be feasible for someone to just bring the Ring to the Undying Lands and give/send it to someone who could safely hold on to it?  Say, perhaps, Eru Ilúvatar, Manwë, Elbereth, Círdan, etc.?  This wouldn't require the person in question to actively intercede in worldly affairs - they would merely have to accept a gift and keep it forever.  Since Humans (and/or Elves and/or Hobbits or whoever) took the initiative in getting the Ring there, it would be more or less the same as bringing it to Mordor and destroying it, but less suffering and loss of life would be required in the process.

So basically, the overall question is:  Why not send the Ring to the Undying Lands?

*Note - since sea monsters never seem to attack ships carrying Elves, Valar, or Maiar to the Undying Lands, despite Sauron's hatred of them, the sea monster issue is irrelevant.  In any case, this question isn't about whether the ship would get there safely if passage were granted - it is about whether passage WOULD be granted and whether it would solve the problem.

*Note 2 - granted, this wouldn't get rid of Sauron, but Aragorn was free to set the terms of the Army of the Dead's deployment.  If he said "You must serve for a thousand years" instead of "You have to fight one battle", then the Army of the Dead could have roamed through Middle-earth and Mordor killing off every Orc and goblin Sauron enlisted.  Sauron would still exist, but he would be a more or less powerless eye stuck on top of a tower, with no hope of raising and army for a thousand years. If Aragorn said "You must serve forever", Sauron would be deprived of an army forever.

Comment: The Ring corrupts anyone who encounters it, and the Elves of Valinor have already been proven to be... imperfectly trustworthy.  If it had been taken to Valinor, it would have sown betrayal and destruction there, which would be even more catastrophic than its effect on Middle Earth.

Comment: @Nerrolken - Not if Eru Iluvatar or Elbereth or Cirdan or Manwe or some such person hid it and kept its presence a secret.

Comment: @Nerrolken - And I would imagine that one or more of these people - especially Eru Iluvatar - could make it cease to exist with little or no effort, or at least render it harmless.  Sauron's power is irrelevant and virtually non-exist compared to Iluvatar's.

Comment: Eru isn't going to get involved, Eru almost *never* interacts with the world.  There's no way Eru is an option.  As for the others, do we have any reason to think they wouldn't be tempted by the Ring?  Maiar can clearly be corrupted by it, so maybe Valar would be immune, but maybe not.  And even if they were immune, would the messengers who brought it be tempted by it, or the people tasked with guarding it?  The Ring's preservative effects would be especially tempting for the Elves...  Plus, as long as the Ring survives, Sauron survives, so destroying it is better than safely hiding it away.

Comment: @Nerrolken - If Frodo can bring it to Mordor (resisting it for 2 years), he can bring it to the Undying Lands (resisting it for a month or less).  None of the Elves tried to take it from him, and the book suggests some of them are basically immune to it (Elrond and Glorfindel at the very least).  Reading the description of Elbereth and Manwe in particular, I can't imagine they'd be susceptible to it either.  And Elves are immortal and eternally preserved already, evn more so in the Undying Lands - that makes its preservative effects superfluous to them.

Comment: As for Eru not getting involved, I assumed he was the one who resurrected Gandalf and made him even more powerful than before - I consider that involvement.  In my theoretical scenario, he'd only have to accept the Ring when it was brought to him - he'd barely have to do anything at all, and his involvement would be totally passive, unless he agreed to destroy it when it was brought to him.

Comment: The Undying Lands aren't a Club Med that any joker in Middle Earth can plan on going to and using for his own purposes. The Valar sent the Istari to help, and that was it.

Comment: @Oldcat El̠ves can go there whenever they want.  Frodo and Bilbo and Gimli went there.  The people who would bring the Ring there in this scenario are people we know went there anyway.

Comment: @Richard - The trip to Aman/Valinor seems to be less like a sea voyage and more like space travel.

Comment: @Richard: There's no reason to believe the voyage to Valinor would be perilous due to sea monsters; it's just that the Ring wouldn't be safe at the bottom of the ocean for all eternity.

Comment: The answer has been given a couple of times; they won't take it. However, Since the Eagles are showing themselves to be an airline service, why not dispense with walking from Rivendell to Mordor and just fly the friendly skies of Thorondor? If the Eagles flew the Fellowship to Orodruin, they'd be there in a matter of hours, surprise the heck out of Sauron and could just toss the Ring in.

Comment: @Mithoron - You are probably right

Comment: @ckirmser - The only answer seems to be that the story would suck if that was what happened.
http://www.sean-crist.com/personal/pages/eagles/

Comment: Lately there was a question about destroying the ring with Thangorodrim so probably all resonable ideas were disputed here long time ago ;)

Comment: Given the nature of the ring, I doubt it could even enter the Undying Lands.

Comment: "the Eagles are showing themselves to be an airline service"... in my opinion, this critique is only applicable to Peter Jackson's take on Middle Earth (and is in fact one of my least favorite things about his movies). Have you read the books?

Comment: @KyleStrand - calling the Eagles an airline service is a bit much, obviously, but they do plenty to help out in the books.  See this link: http://www.sean-crist.com/personal/pages/eagles/

Comment: @WadCheber I didn't say they don't "help out". My problem with the movies is that there is *no* attempt to develop the eagles as *characters*; they don't even talk!

Comment: @KyleStrand - I feel you.  I'm guessing that the issue was time - even without the Eagles being developed fully, each film was at least 3 hours long when it was released.  The extended versions released on DVD were each over 4 hours.  They had to sacrifice a lot to cut the films down to manageable lengths (even 3 hours is a lot to ask an audience to sit through these days), and so we lost Radagast, Glorfindel, Gildor, Tom Bombadil, Gloin, the Eagles, and much, much more.

Comment: @WadCheber That's reasonable for the LotR trilogy, but when they were adapting The Hobbit (~300 pages, maybe?) into a 9-plus-hour monstrosity, they could have made time.

Comment: @KyleStrand I still haven't seen the Hobbit trilogy.  I'm reading LotR for the first time right now (almost done with Fellowship of the Ring), and I think I'll wait until I have read The Hobbit before I watch the movies.  The collection of books I bought includes all 3 LotR books and The Hobbit, so I should be done with all of them in a couple of weeks.

Comment: @WadCheber Don't ever watch the Hobbit movies.

Comment: @KyleStrand - I have to, if only to see Ian McKellen as Gandalf again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23521/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-wad-cheber).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Can Sauron get to Aman?

This is unclear. As [dlanod's answer to the linked question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20298/31051) notes, Aman has been removed from the circles of the world, and is only accessible via the Straight Way. The Elves are, of course, allowed to follow this road to Aman.

What's unclear to me is how the Straight Way works. There are a lot of unknowns.

For example, it's possible that the Straight Way is accessible by any ship on the correct bearing. If so, then Sauron could probably build his own ships and (eventually) find it.

It's also possible that the Elven-ships are under some enchantment that allows only them to pass into Aman. If so, then Sauron would have to fight all the way to the Grey Havens (before the inhabitants destroyed all the ships). It would be supremely unlikely to succeed, but not impossible.

Finally, it's possible that the Valar themselves individually decide whether each ship is allowed to pass into Aman. The odds of them letting Sauron through are astronomically slim.

However, even if Sauron *could* get to Aman, he's not dumb enough to try. It's worth noting that when he sends Ar-Pharazôn and his men to invade Valinor, *Sauron stayed behind:*

> For Sauron himself was filled with great fear at the wrath of the Valar, and the doom that Eru laid upon sea and land. It was greater far than aught he had looked for, hoping only for the death of the Númenóreans and the defeat of their proud king. And Sauron, sitting in his black seat in the midst of the Temple, had laughed when he heard the trumpets of Ar-Pharazôn sounding for battle; and again he had laughed when he heard the thunder of the storm;
>
> <sup><sub>*The Silmarillion* IV *Akallabêth*</sub></sup>

Granted, this takes place relatively early in Sauron's role as Dark Lord; he has grown more powerful in the intervening millenia. But he's not strong enough to contend with all the Valar combined, and that's assuming they don't call on Eru again.

Trying to invade Aman is suicide, and Sauron knows it.

### Is the Ring dangerous if it's beyond Sauron's grasp?

This is unknowable, but I submit to you that it's the wrong question to ask. A better question would be "is *Sauron* still dangerous if the Ring is beyond his grasp?", and the answer it a resounding "Yes." Even without the Ring, the Elves consider Sauron's victory to be practically inevitable. I can't point to any particular quote, but that's the general tone of the Council of Elrond.

Of course the ultimate danger of leaving the Ring undestroyed (even if it's beyond Sauron's grasp forever), is that there is no other way of destroying Sauron. This is covered by [Why was the One Ring such a problem?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58603/why-was-the-one-ring-such-a-problem)

### Is Elrond strong enough to resist the Ring?

Ultimately, no; Elrond would succumb like everyone else. Tolkien himself says this in [Letter 246](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_246):

> Elrond or Galadriel would have proceeded in the policy now adopted by Sauron: they would have built up an empire with great and absolutely subservient generals and armies and engines of war, until they could challenge Sauron and destroy him by force.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 246: To Mrs. Eileen Elgar (Draft). September 1963</sub></sup>

### Could the Ring be taken to Aman?

No. This is discussed in the Council of Elrond, and Elrond himself rejects it:

> 'Then if the Ring cannot be kept from him for ever by strength' said Glorfindel, 'two things only remain for us to attempt: to send it over the Sea, or to destroy it.'
>
> 'But Gandalf has revealed to us that we cannot destroy it by any craft that we here possess,' said Elrond. `And they who dwell beyond the Sea would not receive it: for good or ill it belongs to Middle-earth; it is for us who still dwell here to deal with it.'
>
> <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book 2 Chapter 2: "The Council of Elrond"</sub></sup>

Comment: Now THIS seems like the authoritative answer.  But as to Sauron reaching Aman, he can't.  It isn't a matter of sailing in the right direction - Aman/Valinor is now a different planet from Arda, and no one can get there uninvited.

Comment: @JasonBaker: Would you consider adding a line about the futility of merely keeping the Ring from Sauron (since he'd win without it) so I can delete my answer? :)

Comment: @WadCheber I'm not fully convinced; the only thing Tolkien tells us is "Aman is removed" and "the Elves can still get there." Maybe the Elf-ships are magic, maybe the Elves were given the magic heading, maybe the Valar personally approve or reject everyone who tries it. In the absence of Tolkien telling us explicitly, I'm erring on the side of caution

Comment: @Shamshiel I'm thinking through how I want to phrase that idea, but I'm on mobile at the moment. I'll edit when I get back on my laptop

Comment: @JasonBaker - From the Tolkien Gateway entry on the Akallabeth:  "Arda was made spherical at this time, and Aman was put beyond it, out of the reach of mortal Men."  A spherical Arda with Aman "put beyond it" means Arda is now one planet and Aman is another.

Comment: You know its kind of stupid that the Valar wouldn't take the ring back.  They were willing to break their prime directive to send Gandalf over.  Why not just take the ring and avoid a lot of bloodshed?  Seems a little absurd, especially since Sauron is a former servant of one of their own.  I'm sure Tolkien had some hand-waving mythical reason for the end of the third age, but it just seems like a plot hole.

Comment: @MarkRogers - Amen.  The Valar are very selective when it comes to following their own rules.  And refusing to take the Ring back seems to amount to saying "We made the mess, but the rules we made up say you have to clean it up without our help"

Comment: @JasonBaker - From the Tolkien Gateway entry on Aman:  "In light of this development, the land of Aman was decisively and forever isolated from the other lands. **The flat Arda was cloven in two, and the rest was made round, so that a mariner sailing west along Eärendil's route would simply emerge in the far east. For the Elves, however, a Straight Road remains that peels away from the curvature of the earth and passes to Aman.**"

Comment: @WadCheber I'm not disagreeing with any of that, but the mechanics of *how* (or if) the Elves find the Straight Way and how (or if) the Valar prevent those without permission from using it are never made clear; that's what I'm referring to

Comment: @Shamshiel - sorry - I noticed this answer and accepted it before I saw yours.

Comment: Bilbo and Gimli went to Valinor as a reward for saving the world.  Not because they were destined to. Sailing out with their tails between their legs to avoid the problem would ipso facto make them unworthy.

Comment: @Oldcat - Bilbo didn't really do much to save the world in LotR, and the fact that the world needed to be saved in LotR implies that he didn't save it in The Hobbit either.

Comment: @Oldcat - And if the trip would save the world, allowing them to make the trip would serve the same purpose as the trip in LotR, albeit a bit prematurely (that is, they would take the trip before saving the world, because the trip itself would be how they saved the world).

Comment: You have to read the Music of the Ainur right at the beginning of the Silmarillon to understand much of Eru's mind and purpose. Looks like Arda is a kind of school for Ainurs and children of Illuvatar. He's the teacher and puts the variables in, but he lets his pupils compute.

Comment: @WadCheber - It would save nothing, since Sauron would still be alive and able to dominate Middle Earth.

Comment: @Oldcat - that seems clear now.

Comment: @Oldcat - something just occurred to me.  Aragorn could have told the undead army that they had to serve for however long he wished.  If the Ring was sent to Aman, the undead army could just roam through Mordor for centuries killing everything they saw, and occasionally sweeping through the west killing every Orc and goblin they came across.  Sauron would still exist, but he'd be almost powerless, because every time he started to build an army, it would be annihilated by invincible murder-ghosts.  Problem solved.

Comment: @WadCheber and then [Aragorn would become the next Sauron](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34286/why-didnt-aragorn-keep-going-with-the-army-of-the-dead)

Comment: @TravisChristian how?  He wouldn't have the Ring, and he'd be using the army to keep Sauron at bay, not to maintain his hold on power.

Answer (score 7):

You're assuming that 'fate shortcuts' can be taken - which in Tolkien's legendarium generally is not the case:

- Can't Eru just prevent Melkor from conspiring to alter creation? (i.e. put him in the penalty box or something?)
- Can't the Valar just gang up on Melkor to begin with and watch over him to make sure he doesn't spoil Arda any further?
- Can't the Valar have a bunch of guards watching the two trees in case, oh, I dunno, some errant spider wanders by? They have plenty of unemployed Maya shuffling about after all, right?
- Can't the Valar just take the Silmarils from Melkor and use them/give them back to Fëanor/destroy them?
- Can't the Noldor just multiply enough to kick Melkor's ass? "Come on, Darling, I know you have a headache, but we really have to - remember the oath of Fëanor!"
- Can't Mairon just fly around in his magic bat form for a while and figure out where Nargothrond and/or Gondolin are?
- ...
- [Shall I go on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2K0_Y_PggaA)?

It's a mythology, they're epic tales, not engineering problems. So, of course not.

Comment: I agree (this is why having the Eagles carry Frodo to Mordor so he can get there in hours, instead of years, would work, but would make the story one that isn't worth telling), but I  was looking for an in-universe answer.

Comment: So you got your answer: "Maybe we can - but we won't. Nya na-na na-na na."

Comment: Not sure the eagles taking Frodo to Mordor would have worked. They would have been spotted very fast on Sauron's radar and would have been countered with all his might, including himself coming down from Barad-Dur, Nazguls and making Orodruin erupt. Also, Eru is creating a show for all to see, he will make small fate shortcuts, like Bilbo finding the ring, or Pippin and Merry meeting Treebeard exactly at the right time, but he won't make big ones like directly kicking Sauron's ass !

Comment: Can I have 42.1 km/s of delta V for a payload of 15 grams?

Comment: @Joel - this guy makes a very compelling case for the Eagles being a viable option. http://www.sean-crist.com/personal/pages/eagles/

Comment: I heard that Gandalf just wanted the achievement for having Hobbits carry the ring into Mordor on foot.

Comment: @WadCheber: I have to admit that most of his arguments are hard to refute. I guess we'll have to make do with the idea that Manwë would not let them do it, even though he would let them intervene when humans and hobbits only need a little help from their friends ;-)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: It's like playing [Battle for Wesnoth](http://wesnoth.org) and only ever recruiting [Elvish Shamans](http://units.wesnoth.org/1.10/mainline/en_US/Elvish%20Shaman.html)...

Comment: @Joshua: Your wish is granted. But - you didn't specify in which direction, so the effect might not be quite what you expected. Although I must say I don't understand why people don't pray for specifics like that: "Almighty God, will though not bless this payload of 15g with a Delta-V of 42.1km/s in Azimuth so-and-so and elevation so-and-so?"

Answer (score 5):

The answer to (4) is a resounding no. It was discussed in the Council of Elrond chapter.

> But Gandalf has revealed to us that we cannot destroy it by any craft that we here 
>   possess,' said Elrond. `And they who dwell beyond the Sea would not receive it: for 
>   good or ill it belongs to Middle-earth; it is for us who still dwell here to deal with it.'

The answer to (2) and (3) is yes, the Ring is dangerous even outside Sauron's influence, and no, Elrond is not immune.

> In any case Elrond or Galadriel would have proceeded in the policy now adopted by Sauron: they would have built up an empire with great and absolutely subservient generals and armies and engines of war, until they could challenge Sauron and destroy him by force. (Letters)

Even if Elrond was far away from Sauron. In the same Letter, Tolkien describes what Gandalf would have done after vanquishing Sauron forever:

> Gandalf as Ring-Lord would have been far worse than Sauron. He would have remained ‘righteous’, but self-righteous. He would have continued to rule and order things for ‘good’, and the benefit of his subjects according to his wisdom (which was and would have remained great).

But more importantly, Sauron's victory was inevitable *with or without* the Ring. So merely hiding the Ring, or taking it to Valinor, would not have helped.

Answer (score 2):

If the ring is destroyed, then so is Sauron. So even if he cant get to it, he still has power, and a huge orc army. The ring is just a way to ensure his victory.

Comment: But without the Ring, he is less powerful - hence the desire to keep it away from him.

Answer (score 2):

Eru isn't going to get involved, Eru has only interacted with the world 2-3 times since its creation, and *never* at the request of a simple Man or Elf. He's not going to step in to do a minor favor for some random people, just because they'd rather not walk to Mordor.

As for the others, do we have any reason to think they wouldn't be tempted by the Ring? The Ring corrupts anyone who encounters it, and the Elves of Valinor have already been proven to be... imperfectly trustworthy. Maiar can clearly be corrupted by it, so maybe Valar would be immune, but maybe not.  Aulë, certainly, would likely admire the craftmanship (remember that both Sauron and Saruman were Maiar under Aulë's domain), and we know that he already has had conflicts with other Vala (over the creation of the Dwarves).

And even if the Valar were immune *and* you could get something as evil as the Ring to Valinor in the first place (again not a guarantee), would the messengers who brought it be tempted by it, or the people tasked with guarding it?  Remember, it's not just the journey to Valinor, it's the journey *across* Valinor and the entire duration of its containment there (that is, all of eternity).  The Ring's preservative effects would be especially tempting for the Elves, who are constantly yearning to slow down the world and keep it from changing.  Even if you gave it to Manwë and Manwë *did* turn out to be immune, the Ring famously breeds treachery.  It could cause another rebellion of the Elves, or worse, the fall of a Maia or Vala, and thus the creation of a *new* Sauron or even Morgoth.

Plus, as long as the Ring survives, Sauron survives, so destroying it is better than safely hiding it away.  Even if it was safely out of Sauron's reach, he would still be free to devastate Middle-earth.  Hardly a satisfactory scenario, given that the whole reason for keeping the Ring away from him is to stop him from devastating Middle-earth.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I disagree on some of the details. If Frodo can bring it to Mordor (resisting it for 2 years), he can bring it to the Undying Lands (resisting it for a month or less). None of the Elves tried to take it from him, and the book suggests some of them are basically immune to it (Elrond and Glorfindel at the very least). Reading the description of Elbereth and Manwe in particular, I can't imagine they'd be susceptible to it either. And Elves are immortal and eternally preserved already, even more so in the Undying Lands - its preservative effects are superfluous to them.

Comment: Gandalf pooh-poohs the idea of dropping it into the ocean. "*There are many things in the deep waters*". Presumably the same applies to taking it on a ship. Too risky, too public.

Comment: And treachery against someone as powerful as Manwe is meaningless.  How could anyone rob a guy who is basically a god?

Comment: Just updated my answer: what makes you think Frodo would be successful sailing to Valinor with such an evil thing?  I expect he'd just sail right past, just like a Man or Dwarf attempting the same voyage.  And as for the Elves, they wouldn't want to preserve themselves, it's well-known that they want to preserve *the world*, slow it down so it doesn't decay.

Comment: @WadCheber You could steal from Manwe if YOU are a god, like Aule, or if you are treacherous, like Morgoth and Ungoliant.  Hell, the armies of Numenor [successfully threatened the Valar](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72543/20221), and they were just Men.  Remember, the Valar are Greek-style "gods", who are capable of losing a fight.

Comment: @Richard - Bilbo used it at a party in front of hundreds of people.  Dozens saw it at Rivendell.  It has been in many places more public than a ship containing a few Elves, a Wizard, and two ringbearers.

Comment: @Nerrolken - then Eru basically made Valinor a separate, unreachable planet.  No one gets there uninvited now.

Comment: @WadCheber Exactly.  After the Second Age, Valinor can't be reached simply by sailing west.  You have to be "allowed" to reach it, and I doubt anyone carrying such evil would be allowed.  What I meant by the "armies of Numenor" comment was that stealing from Manwe isn't a crazy notion.  Anyone can do it, if they're strong enough.

Comment: @Nerrolken - Frodo wouldn't be steering the ship, and it sounds like no one steers ships to the Undying Lands - they have no sails or oars.  If he resisted it on a 2 year long hike (and Bilbo resisted it for 60 years), resisting it on a boat for a month or less should be no sweat.

Comment: @Nerrolken - Gandalf was allowed to bring an evil palantir to the Undying Lands.

Comment: @WadCheber You're missing my point.  If a boat of humans sails west in the Third Age, they won't reach Valinor.  It simply won't be there.  It's a magical journey, you have to be worthy for Valinor to be reachable.  Gandalf took a palantir which [was never used by Sauron](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/35352/20221).  The Ring is evil, innately.  Practically evil incarnate.  I'm saying, if Frodo had sailed west with the Ring, Valinor simply wouldn't have appeared.

Comment: @Nerrolken - that sounds like opinion.  The ship would be carrying the same people who ended up going to Valinor anyway - Frodo, Bilbo, Gandalf, Elrond, and some other Elves.  I was also under the impression that Sauron made the palantir himself for his own (inherently evil) purposes.

Comment: @WadCheber: Palantir are not evil. They were made by Feanor to faciliate long-range communication and to see things far away. It's just that bad people can use them - Sauron stole his from Gondor. Also, Morgoth got robbed by a Man and an Elf, and he was also a god.

Comment: @WadCheber Sauron didn't make the [Palantiri](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Palant%C3%ADri).  And check out Jason Baker's answer for proof that Valinor wouldn't accept the Ring.

Comment: @Shamshiel - Morgoth<Manwe.

Comment: @WadCheber: Morgoth was the mightest of the Ainur. He was so powerful that literally everything in Middle-Earth contains a piece of Morgoth and his will.

Comment: @Shamshiel - for someone who is more powerful than Manwe, Morgoth is awfully dead.  Manwe being alive and apparently immortal suggests that Manwe>Morgoth.

Comment: @WadCheber Really?  Morgoth single-handedly fought the whole host of the Valar for thousands of years, but you think his final defeat is a sign that Manwe is more powerful?  Manwe wasn't even the one who defeated Morgoth.  It's really [not in dispute](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Melkor) that Melkor was greater than Manwe: *"However, the other Valar took Manwë to be their lord, for while Manwë was not nearly so powerful as Melkor, he understood the thought of Eru better than any of his peers."*

Comment: One does not simply get favors from Eru.